# Appropriate title case: 'em or 'Em or 'EM

Tags: orthography, capitalization, contractions, titles

It's a common practice to capitalize headings/titles of articles. But is there a correct or conventional way to capitalize words in titles that are <del>[apocopated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apocopate)</del>  [apheresed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apheresis#Noun) at the beginning?

E.g.

> Disable Feeds (Make 'em Inaccessible) On Your Site

Yes, I do understand that using *Them* instead of *'em* would be more proper, but I really wanted to know about this anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should initial e's after h-dropping be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48048/should-initial-es-after-h-dropping-be-capitalized)

Comment: @MEd: But that question does not address title case, which is not the same as ordinary capitalization...

Comment: I would capitalize your sample title as follows: _Disable Feeds (Make 'em Inaccessible) on Your Site_ (lower-case _o_ on _on_). As for the _'em_ (the crux of this question), I'd leave it lower-case, reason being that the missing _t_ would've been capitalized, but, just because it's gone, we don't promote the _e_. An exception would be when the apheresed word is the first word of the title: _'Tis the Season, 'Twas the Night Before Christmas_, e.g. However, all this is only a hunch and I don't know of any authoritative source that would back me up (ergo, all you get is a comment from me).

Comment: meta: Wonder who is up voting OT/ Dupe questions. This is getting too much already.

Comment: @Kris If only you read the second comment under the question.

Comment: @J.R. And in your case, you use lowercase for all two-letter words? (How about three-letter words like `the`, `put`, etc. What's the... 'er... formula? How do you do it?)

Comment: The comment above was **not** for the OP.

Comment: @61: No, it's not the _length_ of the word that is significant, it's its _part of speech_. You can read about what "most" style guides say at [this web page](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles/), and [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/capitalizing-titles.aspx) writes about this as well.

Comment: I would capitalize 'Em exactly when you would capitalize Them. You would capitalize "Them" in this title, so I would capitalize "'Em". However, I have no evidence for this, so it's only a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Chicago Manual of Style*'s convention on headline-style capitalization does not mention words beginning with apostrophes (8.157–159). It gives seven rules. The first rule is to capitalize the first and last word of titles and subtitles (e.g., ***'Twas*** the Night Before Christmas), and the other six concern part of speech. This would seem to indicate whether to capitalize a word beginning with an apostrophe should depend on its placement within the title and part of speech, and would in your case give you "Make 'Em Inaccessible," which to me looks terribly awkward.

However, before laying out its seven rules, the *Manual* says

> The conventions of headline style are governed mainly by emphasis and grammar.

This hints at what it later says explicitly; the rules are arbitrary.

In a previous edition (the 15th, 8.167), it says

> If you are not sure what grammatical function a word is performing (or even if you are), try reading the title aloud: if you would stress the word, capitalize it; if not, lowercase it.

This would seem to indicate "Make 'em Inaccessible." Up to you whether you want to go with the more rigid current recommendations or the more subjective guideline the *Manual* prescribed ages ago (in 2003).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted practice appears to be to carve out an exception to the normal rules of titling.  Consider the play *Give ’em Hell, Harry!*, whose title has an *’em* in it — in that literal capitalization.

Comment: Relevant link: ***[Give 'em Hell, Harry!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Give_%27em_Hell%2c_Harry!)*** (Wikipedia)